# How to fit an existing curve to a few additional points (minimized residual?)

Tags: matlab, surface

So what I want to do is to parallel shift an EXISTING (theoretical) surface to a few points which I have measured. I don't want to create/fit a surface to these points. The surface must be the same, only move not transform. The surface should therefore only be moved along one axis in order to minimize the residual.
I think there is an easy way to do that but I do not know how to do that.

Screenshot of the Surface and the points. The Surface have to move "to the points"

[image: Screenshot of the Surface and the points. The Surface have to move "to the points"]

Comment: Just add a value. If you know the value of the surface at the point x,y, you just need to add the heigh difference to all the z in the surface.

Comment: The problem is that I have more than 10 points at the end not only two. And the other problem is that I don't have a formula of the surface. It's only a interpolated point cloud and the values of the point are not exactly on the x and y points of the surface.
I hope it is understandable.

But thank you for your idea.. maybe I could calcute the sum of all deviations in positive and negative direction and use it as offset..

But how can I calculate the deviation without a exact formula of the surface?

Comment: Ok with fit and poly23 and I have calculated a formula with which I can calculate each deviation between a point and the surface in z direction.
Thank you @AnderBiguri for your inspiration!

Comment: You may need to extend the description of your problem in the post, otherwise its too vague

Comment: Just to make it clear - the surface should only have rigid movement? It should not get distorted in some way, just shifted?